# Overlapping split and merge of large text file

Tags: perl, text, awk

I have a big file (100 GB +).
I want to parallel process it. I want to split it so the first file will contain line 0 to 1001 M the second file from 1000 M to 2001 M etc.
After I process the files I have n overlapping lines between each two results (n is bounded but not constant. let's assume n can range between 100-900 k lines. The overlapping can happen only in line level)
is there some way to achieve this task or do i have to write the splitting and merging using C?

Comment: It would be much more useful if you showed us a small example of what you want to do (and preferably, your attempt at doing it). Of course, it's useful to know that you intend on working with much larger files but the principles are likely to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to re-invent the wheel

Map/Reduce and it's implementation in [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/) was invented for exactly "I have a big file (100 GB +). I want to parallel process it."

Since the invention of Hadoop, there have been many many additions to the bigdata toolbox. I would suggest you look into [spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and maybe [python-spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/python-programming-guide.html), if you like C, then you probably will like python. It's quite a natural next step (if not C++ first) in my opinion.

Otherwise, splitting files can be done with bash by stacking [tee](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) commands in streams with [head](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and [tail](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) attached to the output streams. You would have to do a binary split in each step, basically halving the file in each step. The command gets quite complicated but I have done this before and it does work. Just don't expect the code you produce to be understandable by someone else, it gets very very messy. I would advice against persuing this line of work and use something that already has been tested and proven, such as [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can use awk to split a file into overlapping chunks:

```
BEGIN { file_f = -1 }          # initialise file suffix
{ l = NR % 20 }                # 20 is the repeat length
l == 1  { f = 1; file_f += 2 } # f is set for lines 1 to 12, inclusive
l == 13 { f = 0 }
l == 11 { g = 1; file_g +=2 }  # g is set for lines 11 to 2, inclusive
l == 3  { g = 0 }
f { print >"file_"file_f }
g { print >"file_"file_g }
```

The flag `f` handles "odd" chunks and `g` handles "even" ones. The `file_f` and `file_g` suffixes are incremented by 2 for each new chunk, resulting in consecutively numbered output files.

Testing this out on a small example (note that line numbers in awk start from 1):

```
$ seq 22 > file
$ awk -f script.awk file
$ cat file_1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
$ cat file_2
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
$ cat file_3
21
22
```